# Jodhaa Bai as Emperor Akbar's wife?

Tags: india, mughals

Was Jodhaa bai the elder daughter of Rajput King Bharmal actually emperor Akbar's wife ??
Various texts refer to her as Mariam and Jahangir's mother, the successor of Akbar.
Well, The Jahangirnama written by Jahangir as such doesn't mention Jodhaa bai but it does mention about Mariam as his mother.
Some texts also refer Jodhaa bai as Jahangir's wife.
The Akbarnama written in three volumes by Abul Fazal- one of the nine jems in Akbar's court also does not cite Jodhaa bai.

So, my question is did Jodhaa bai exist?
If yes then what was her true identity- Mariam, princess of amber,akbar's third wife, Jahangir's mother or Jahangir's wife?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to have been a mixup of names at some time during history:

> Jodha Bai was not the name of Akbar's Rajput queen. It was, in fact, the name of Jahangir's Rajput wife, whose real name was Jagat Gosain. Since she belonged to the royal family of Jodhpur, she was also referred to as Jodha Bai.
>   ...
>   The myth of Jodha Bai being Akbar's Rajput wife, says Irfan Habib, probably gained credence during the 19th century when guides at Fatehpur Sikri gave her the mantle of Akbar's wife, a perception which is prevalent even today.

http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2007-06-24/india/27967423_1_asoka-islam-throne

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariam_uz-Zamani Well, this article states Jodhaa bai as princess of Amer...

Comment: @AanalDesai: Actualy it doesn't if you read it properly. But it's mostly confused. Wikipedia is not a reliable source.

Answer (score 1):

Akbar married a Rajput princess of Amer.

The princess was the elder daughter of Raja Bharmal and the aunt of Man Singh, who was one of the nine jewels of Akbar. She was the third queen of Akbar; in many places her name was referred to as Mariam-uz-zamini.

In Jahangirnama it is mentioned that his mother was a Rajput princess who was an elder daughter of Raja Bharmal of Amer; but her name is mentioned as mariam-uz-zamini which was a title given to her. So her name was not mariam-uz-zamini, it was just a title given to her. Jahangir's wife's name was Jodh Bai not Jodha Bai.

So, in conclusion - Akbar married a Rajput princess but the princess' name is not confirmed.

Comment: Welcome to History Stackexchange! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and learn about the do's and don'ts here. In particular, it is very much desired to give the source of the information in one's answer.

Answer (score -4):

Ok i've done a research. Jodha bai were titles given to princesses of amer then.her real name is heer kunwari;miriam was a title given to her when she married akbar.this justifies why both her and salim's wife are reffered to as jodha. Yes i believe she exisisted and had powerful influence on akbar. Visit miriam and jahangir's wikis you will get to knw that miriam was indeed also known as jodha